# Ember Data - re-commit current transaction

Tags: forms, transactions, ember.js, commit, ember-data

I have a button that submits the whole form to the server. Sometimes the server responds with errors and the users need to change/update the fields and submit again (common sense?). I'm using this (coffeescript):

```
@transaction.commit()
```

However, as I can see from Ember Data - DS.Transaction https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/transaction.js#L161

```
...
Once you call `commit()` on a transaction, you should not re-use it.

When a record is saved, it will be removed from this transaction and
moved back to the store's default transaction.
```

So, how should I submit the form again without refreshing and filling all the data?

Answer (score 0):

The record will still be attached to the transaction, you can can reuse it.

Just keep in mind that if you had multiple records attached/committed at the same time, those that were successfully saved are moved to the store's default transaction.

Comment: Hi Cyril! As I see in the unit tests of Transaction https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/transactions/basic_test.js#L247, the records are no longer DIRTY after the transaction rolls back. I can't see the tests for failed committed transaction. Should it be the same behaviour? I would like the records to stay dirty so that just another click will work.

Comment: Rolling back puts the record in the last clean state, so this won't work the way you want it.

Comment: It's not really what I want actually ... :(